# Cubic Polynomial in Python

Tags: python-3.x

For my latest project in my coding class (python), we need to program and compute a cubic function. So something like 3x^3+2x^2+7x+1. I cannot figure out how to code in the different x powers. I know this is a very simple question, but I can't find what I am looking for on the internet and have searched. How would I write out this polynomial given the 3,2,7 & 1 values? I assume I need to use numpy but can only figure that out with a degree one polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

powers can be represented with [`**`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) in python (there is also a more sophisticated [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)) function:

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 7*x + 1
```

(in python [`^`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) is the `xor` operator; if you use your expression python would not complain but just not calculate what you want)

---

if you need to be able to do symbolic math, i suggest you install the [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/) package:

```
from sympy import symbols

def f(x):
    return 3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 7*x + 1

x = symbols('x')

print(f(x))            # 3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 7*x + 1
print(f(x).subs(x, 5)) # 461
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! My only issue is that I don't know how to define x as a variable in the code. I can't do multiplication with numbers and variables unless the variable is defined by some number, instead of a general variable. I know how to graph with matplotlib and numpy, but cannot figure out how to get an equation as my output.

Comment: I am not inputing a list or something as x, I need a general x.

Comment: for that you would need a 3rd-party library. i suggest you look into sympy.org . hang on, i'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom function like this example:

```
def cubic(x, args):
    args_len = len(args)
    for k in args:
        yield k * x ** (args_len-1)
        args_len -=1
```

Demo:

```
user_input = [3, 2, 7, 1]
user_var_x  = 1
somme = sum(cubic(user_var_x, user_input))
print(somme)
```

Output:

```
13
```